# Unconfirmed transaction since 2 days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

2 days ago I've send some btc from my Bitcoin wallet called Bitcoin-QT(Version v0.8.6) to my Kraken account.
But it is still unconfirmed and still don't see anything on Kraken too.

Last week I did exactly the same thing(send my same Kraken adresse), and I received my coins a half day later on my Kraken account..

So what can be wrong here? Maybe because of the old BTC wallet version?
I'm feeling a little stressed now..

Thanks in advance.

Grtz,

A BTC Noob

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the fee was very low and it is therefore not being selected by miners for a block. Bitcoin-Qt 0.8.6 is from Dec 2013 and you should consider upgrading to a newer version of the software. The recent versions have vastly improved fee estimation.

You should probably try to doublespend the transaction with a bigger fee. You can find more information and detailed instructions on [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406).

Comment: The fee was very low so can be right. But the last time the fee was also 0.0001 BTC so thats why I did the same. But thank you, the next time I will do a higher fee.

Comment: Perhaps the transaction was bigger? Most miners have moved to evaluating a transaction's fee in [satoshi/byte], so bigger transactions would have a smaller fee rate.

Comment: But if I want to update my wallet I have to delete this version... so its maybe better to wait untill this transacion has been confirmed? Because what if the btc will be sent back because the low fee?

Comment: Aah okay, clear:) Yes, that transaction was bigger.

Comment: BTC_CZ: Definitely keep a backup of your `wallet.dat`! You can continue to use the `wallet.dat` in your new version of Bitcoin. The `wallet.dat` stores your private keys and information on all transactions you performed and is the single irreplaceable part of your wallet.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thanks for your fast reply!

Comment: Helle Murch, here I am again..

I've downloaded the update version of Bitcoin Core.. But the Old Bitqoin-QT version is still shown @ my programs.. When I click this program it says that it can't be openend..

I can open the new version, but this one I don't see @ my programs..
When I open it I see that my transaction from last Friday is still unconformed (And I still don't see anything at the receive adresse on my Kraken account:( )

I feel really stressed and dont know what to do to have my btc back..

Do you know maybe whats going on?

Comment: @BTC_CZ: What operating system are you using? Your transaction had probably a fee that was so low that no miner selected your transaction for a block yet. This means that your BTC are still in your wallet, it's just the wallet that thinks they are going to be spent, because it created a transaction. No worries!

Comment: @BTC_CZ: What you now want to do is to convince your wallet that the transaction is not going to happen. To that end, you'll make it forget the unconfirmed transaction. You can do that by starting your Bitcoin-Qt with `-zapwallettxes`. This makes it only forget unconfirmed transactions. Then you should send all your bitcoins to yourself so that the old transaction cannot be confirmed anymore. Finally, you create a new transaction to send money to Kraken.

Comment: I am using Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.5
How can I start Bitcoin-Qt with -zapwallettxes ?

Many thanks!

Comment: @BTC_CZ: Do you know how to open a Terminal window? You'd run the `.dmg` from there and append `-zapwallettxes`. Alternatively, I think this solution should work: http://superuser.com/a/16777/228234

Comment: Really appreciating your fast help.. I tried to do it but can't get it done..
The problem is that I'm going for a week on holidays now, so unfortunately I have to look at it right when I'll be back..
But I can't loose my btc right? What if there won't be any confirming? 
Then I have to let my wallet 'forget' the unconfirmed transaction and do what you've explained me right? Or will they be back in my wallet if it stays unconfirmed?

Thanks..

Comment: P.S. I managed now to remove the old wallet, so I have the new one visible @ my programs now

Comment: @BTC_CZ: If they stay unconfirmed, they'll still be in your wallet. And you'll be able to make your wallet forget later. If they confirm, your payment goes through.

Comment: Hi Murch.. I'm back from holidays and the BTC are still unconfirmed.. 
Can you please explain me how I need to run the .dmg file from the terminal file and append -zapwallettxes ? Sorry, but I don't get it done..

Thanks again very much.

Kind regards